# How to limit the number of characters returned by each match in grep

Tags: awk, grep

How can I limit the results shown by `grep -rn "sqs" *` to exclude long results (more than say a line or two long)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `find + awk`:

```sh
find . -type f -exec awk 'length() <= 80 && /sqs/ {
print FILENAME ":" FNR ":\033[1;31m" $0 "\033[0m "}' {} +
```

- `length() <= 80` will search `sqs` string in lines that have 80 or less characters in them.
- `"\033[1;31m" $0 "\033[0m "` is used to color the line `red`.

Comment: Thanks.  Works and I will accept but the original command colours `sqs` in orange.  Is that possible?

Comment: It might be possible to color the output in awk but I don't know at present. Will try to figure out

Comment: I have edited awk command to color the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` followed by filtering in Perl, and finally, use the grep **only** to add back the coloring (otherwise, it does not do anything useful, since all lines should match):

```
grep -rn 'sqs' * | perl -ne 'print if length $_ <= 30' | grep 'sqs'
```